# Corner radius in custom UILabel class

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a label in my Storyboard where i subclass a custom class with the following code

```
@IBDesignable class PaddingLabel: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable var topInset: CGFloat = 5.0
    @IBInspectable var bottomInset: CGFloat = 5.0
    @IBInspectable var leftInset: CGFloat = 7.0
    @IBInspectable var rightInset: CGFloat = 7.0

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)
        super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        var intrinsicSuperViewContentSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
        intrinsicSuperViewContentSize.height += topInset + bottomInset
        intrinsicSuperViewContentSize.width += leftInset + rightInset
        return intrinsicSuperViewContentSize
    }
}
```

I've added `label?.layer.cornerRadius = 5` in my custom TableviewCell `awakeFromNib` function.

It doesn't seem to be affecting the label.

Comment: is issue solved ?

Comment: you are using IBDesignable so why not set in your storyboard. easiest way to reset in UI, Even you can compile the piece of code without compiling whole code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add clipsToBounds property:

```
label?.clipsToBounds = true // or use label?.layer.masksToBounds = true
```